# Android i am getting response from web service like

Tags: android, json, xml, web-services

```
START 

D/OkHttp: Specific Gravity Before Charging : 150,150,150,150,150,150

D/OkHttp: Specific Gravity After Charging : 150,150,150,150,150,150

D/OkHttp: Battery Serial : 2bea79b1001000

 D/OkHttp: Battery AH : 150

 D/OkHttp: Battery Type : INVERTER

 D/OkHttp: OCV , 16.0

 D/OkHttp: OCV , 14.5

 D/OkHttp: OCV , 14.5

 D/OkHttp: OCV , 14.5

 D/OkHttp: OCV , 14.5

 D/OkHttp: Inverter DCHG After 02 Hr :

 D/OkHttp: FAN THERMAL SHUTDOWN FAULT

 D/OkHttp: 4,1,0000

 D/OkHttp: 4,2,0000

 D/OkHttp: END
```

How can i parse this response, looks like it is neither in JSON nor in XMLformat.

Comment: Looks like plain text to me. You need to be more specific to your question. We won't write the parser for you mate.

Comment: this kind of response called as Packets, to parse this you should use split(",")

Answer (score 0):

Use split function first toget all lines by String[] lines=response.split["\n"] then parse each line with : to separate key and value like lines[i].split(":") then parse each value using split(",")

Answer (score 0):

what kind of data you are expecting to receive.if you are usibg OKHTTP library to receive json or xml, you should receive json or xml contents from Response.body.string method.